# Manage Tab Index in GridView

Tags: winforms, gridview, key-value, tabindex

I have 3 columns in a gridview - code,Qty,name.If a cell(Say Code), is in edit mode, pressing the arrow or tab keys will fire the 'CellEndEdit' event and after that,moves the selection to the next cell. I want to have different selected cell if it is an arrow key and another selected if it is tab. eg:

On Right arrow key: Code -> Qty

On Tab press: Code -> Name

The datagridview's key events(down,up,press) dont fire once the cell enters edit mode.So, how can i get the last pressed key's value when the cell is in edit mode. I have to write the code/method/function in CellEndEdit event. Can this be something like:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)       
{  
  //Some calculations;  
  //Get the key if it is tab or arrow to decide which cell should be selected next  
 If((bool)OnKeyDown()==true)   
    then do this;
}          
void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
 { 
   if(e.KeyValue==9)//tab key     
     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it this way based on a soln. here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0283fe97-c0ad-4768-8aff-cb4d14d48e15/

```
bool IsTabKey;
private void DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)       
{  
   //Some calculations;  
  //Get the key if it is tab or arrow to decide which cell should be selected next  
    If(IsTabKey==true)   
      //then do this;
}  
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if(GridViewSale.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 && keyData == Keys.Tab)
       IsTabKey = true;
       return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a solution from this [`link`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0283fe97-c0ad-4768-8aff-cb4d14d48e15), I was able to come up with something that might be able to help you.

First you want to create your own user class which derives from `DataGridView` and override the `ProcessCmdKey` function. This function will get called regardless of whether or not your cell is in edit mode.

```
public partial class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
        {
            this.CurrentCell = this.Rows[this.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1];
            return true;
        }
        else if (keyData == Keys.Right)
        {
            this.CurrentCell = this.Rows[this.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[2];
            return true;
        }
        else
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

All you need to do now is change the logic inside of this function to go to the appropriate column depending on the key which has been pressed, and use this custom class instead of the default `DataGridView`.

Comment: Thank you Mash.Sorry that didnt help. I already have several lines of code that say gridview1.rows, gridview1.currentrow etc. So pasting class gridview1:DataGridView threw errors(Or maybe i did it wrong). I also have key events for down and up. Will this procedure not affect them.So, I am looking for a simple alternate. Thank you again.